# Parse django datetime field

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with serialization of datetime field.
I'm using serializers.DateTimeField from django rest framework and I'm getting 400 status when I'm trying to send `2018-09-04T00:00:00+0100` as query param. If timezone offset is negative - it works perfect.

Here is django error:

```
"date": [
        "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."
    ]
```

Also I found all input formats for datetime field and I'm sure that my datetime is valid

```
print(formats.get_format_lazy('DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS'))
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z']
```

Answer (score 1):

the example you are giving is missing `:` which does not make it match the iso8601 format

`2018-09-04T00:00:00+0100` should be `2018-09-04T00:00:00+01:00` - minor detail but significant.

If you read the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield), the only format provided by the serializer is 'iso-8601'

All the formats you mentioned above are not part of the input formats. Make sure you have the right format in your `input_formats` list in your `serializers.DateTimeField`

> Signature: DateTimeField(format=api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT, input_formats=None)
>
> input_formats - A list of strings representing the input formats which may be used to parse the date. If not specified, the DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS setting will be used, which defaults to ['iso-8601'].
>
> Format strings may either be Python strftime formats which explicitly specify the format, or the special string 'iso-8601', which indicates that ISO 8601 style datetimes should be used. (eg '2013-01-29T12:34:56.000000Z')

Comment: In your example Z means utc timezone. For other timezone should your be used positive or negative offset

Comment: updated my answer to be clearer - you are missing `:`

Comment: @This detail isn't important. Still the same behaviour

Comment: then I would check to make to see what data is making it into the request by using the debugger

Comment: The problem is that I can't pass symbol '+' to query params

Comment: use POST or url encode your data before sending it - you should really use POST if this is not a filtering action...

Comment: Unfortunately it's filtering action(

Comment: well, this is not a backend problem - you need to url encode your string properly if you are passing it in the query string